# SAML token size and REST

Tags: saml, wif, claims-based-identity, sts-securitytokenservice

We are implementing STS (claim based authentication) for the the REST based services. One of the reasons amongst many when we decide to create REST services (with JSON) was the small footprint over the wire. With STS, the SAML token with just a few claims the SAML size becomes few K bytes. For most of the REST calls where we are not returning list of objects, the response size is low 100s bytes and for those calls this token seems too much of overhead. How do you dealt with this in your projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SAML tokens with REST endpoints, but more often you will find people using Simple Web Tokens (SWT) instead. Smaller, simpler, etc.

ACS (Access Control Service in Windows Azure PLatform) implements this, for example.

Comment: It doesn't look like SWT is moving forward. JWT also is in infancy. It seems like we have to deal with SAML for now. http://startersts.codeplex.com/discussions/242113?ProjectName=startersts

Answer (score 2):

... Or JWT (JSon Web Token). ACS supports these too.
Check this article: [JSON Web Token Handler for the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2012/11/20/introducing-the-developer-preview-of-the-json-web-token-handler-for-the-microsoft-net-framework-4-5.aspx)
Here is a usage example of this library with .Net 4.5 that issues and validates a JWT signed with symmetric key based HMAC SHA256.

```
string jwtIssuer = "MyIssuer";
string jwtAudience = "MyAudience";

// Generate symmetric key for HMAC-SHA256 signature
RNGCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] keyForHmacSha256 = new byte[64];
cryptoProvider.GetNonZeroBytes(keyForHmacSha256);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Create signing credentials for the signed JWT.
// This object is used to cryptographically sign the JWT by the issuer.
SigningCredentials sc = new SigningCredentials(
                                new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(keyForHmacSha256),
                                "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256",
                                "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Create token validation parameters for the signed JWT
// This object will be used to verify the cryptographic signature of the received JWT
TokenValidationParameters validationParams =
    new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        AllowedAudience = s_jwtAudience,
        ValidIssuer = s_jwtIssuer,
        ValidateExpiration = true,
        ValidateNotBefore = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateSignature = true,
        SigningToken = new BinarySecretSecurityToken(keyForHmacSha256),
    };

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Create JWT handler
// This object is used to write/sign/decode/validate JWTs
JWTSecurityTokenHandler jwtHandler = new JWTSecurityTokenHandler();

// Create a simple JWT claim set
IList<Claim> payloadClaims = new List<Claim>() { new Claim("clm1", "clm1 value"), };

// Create a JWT with signing credentials and lifetime of 12 hours
JWTSecurityToken jwt =
    new JWTSecurityToken(jwtIssuer, jwtAudience, payloadClaims, sc, DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(12.0));

// Serialize the JWT
// This is how our JWT looks on the wire: <Base64UrlEncoded header>.<Base64UrlEncoded body>.<signature>
string jwtOnTheWire = jwtHandler.WriteToken(jwt);

// Validate the token signature (we provide the shared symmetric key in `validationParams`)
// This will throw if the signature does not validate
jwtHandler.ValidateToken(jwtOnTheWire, validationParams);

// Parse JWT from the Base64UrlEncoded wire form (<Base64UrlEncoded header>.<Base64UrlEncoded body>.<signature>)
JWTSecurityToken parsedJwt = jwtHandler.ReadToken(jwtOnTheWire) as JWTSecurityToken;
```

Comment: I can't seem to find any ability to use a symmetric key, with that one. Kind of stuck :-(

Comment: Not sure I understand what do you mean, but, just in case, I updated my answer above to show a piece of code that creates, signs, serializes a JWT and then performs the reverse process.